# Transitioned element with :checked not showing after transition complete

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am creating a transitioned CSS only menu. The approach I am taking is when the menu button is checked (clicked) the menu transitions out from the right side. This is point I am stuck on ... the menu just vanishes after the transition ends; it fades out.

Does anyone see why this is happening and how I can fix it?

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqofj101/)

```css
#mobile-button {
 background-image: url("https://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/menu.png");
  background-size: 30px 30px;
 float: right;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-top: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
 transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
}
#nav-pop {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 height: 100vh;
}
#mobile-check:not(:checked) ~ #nav-pop {
 opacity: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 z-index: 999999;
 transition: ease 0.6s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.6s;
 transform: translateX(0);-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}
#mobile-check:checked ~ #nav-pop {
 float: none;
 opacity: 1;
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: 0;
 width: 70%;
 right: -100%;
 height: 100vh;
 transform: translateX(100%);-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="mobile-check">
<label id="mobile-button" for="mobile-check"></label>
<div id="nav-pop">
  <div id="nav-pop-close"></div>
  <ul id="nav-list">
    <li><a href="about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="services">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="project">PROJECT</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this how it's supposed to look? https://jsfiddle.net/cqofj101/2/

Comment: @cjl750 That functionality is perfect. Thanks! So essentially my initial `right: 0` was conflicting?

Comment: The `right` value was most of it, yeah. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you were going from `right: 0` to `right: -100%`. You were transitioning it *off* screen to the right. I think the only reason you even saw the flash is because you were adding `position: fixed` with `:checked`, so it jumped for a sec before transitioning.

This will be easier if you set standard styles for `#mobile-check ~ #nav-pop` and then just toggle a few of them with `:checked`, like this:

```
#mobile-check ~ #nav-pop {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  right: -100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  z-index: 999999;
  transition: ease 0.6s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.6s;
  transform: translateX(0);-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}
#mobile-check:checked ~ #nav-pop {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 100%;
  transform: translateX(100%);-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

Now, we're *starting* with `position: fixed` at `right: -100%`, and then we're just moving to the left.

```css
#mobile-button {
 background-image: url("https://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/menu.png");
  background-size: 30px 30px;
 float: right;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-top: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
 transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
}
#nav-pop {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 height: 100vh;
}
#mobile-check ~ #nav-pop {
 opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
 right: -100%;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 z-index: 999999;
 transition: ease 0.6s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.6s;
 transform: translateX(0);-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}
#mobile-check:checked ~ #nav-pop {
 opacity: 1;
 right: 100%;
 transform: translateX(100%);-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="mobile-check">
<label id="mobile-button" for="mobile-check"></label>
<div id="nav-pop">
  <div id="nav-pop-close"></div>
  <ul id="nav-list">
    <li><a href="about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="services">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="project">PROJECT</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!